# When does idle dialogue trigger?

Tags: borderlands-2

When idle for long enough, a character speaks special dialogue, often expressing boredom and/or referring to the fact that they are just standing around.

I am asking three questions, here.

1. How long does it take, exactly, before the character speaks idle
   dialogue?
2. When the character speaks, does it take the same amount
   of time before they say more?
3. Is there any input that won't reset the idle timer?